# How do I add an integer input for my program in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input

So I have a program in swing where I am supposed to calculate the cost of staying in a hotel room for "x" amount of weeks.

I want to be able to have the user input "x" but I am not sure what code I would use.  Also Here is my code so far.

```
public class Hotel extends JFrame
{
    int room1 = 0;
    int room2 = 0;
    int weeks;
    int boat = 0;
    JPanel p, p1;
    JLabel l, l1;
    JTextField t, t1;
    JButton b;
    JCheckBox b1, b2, b3;

    Hotel()
    {
        setTitle("Hotel Room Selection");
        setSize(800, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildPanel();
        add(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void buildPanel()
    {
        l = new JLabel("Select a room type");
        l1 = new JLabel("How many weeks will you be staying?");
        b = new JButton("Confirm");
        b1 = new JCheckBox("1 bedroom ($600 per week)");
        b2 = new JCheckBox("2 Bedroom ($850 per week)");
        b3 = new JCheckBox("Rowboat rental ($60 per week)");

        p = new JPanel();
        p1 = new JPanel();
        add(p);
        p.add(l);
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        p.add(b3);
        p.add(l1);
        p.add(b);
        add(p1);

        b.addActionListener(new buttonlistener());
        b1.addItemListener(new cbListener());
        b2.addItemListener(new cbListener());
        b3.addItemListener(new cbListener());
        setVisible(true);

    }

    class buttonlistener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String i = t.getText();
            int val = Integer.parseInt(i);
            val = (room1 + room2 + boat) * weeks;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total is " + val);
        }
    }

    class cbListener implements ItemListener
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent b)
        {
            if (b.getSource() == b1)
            {
                if (b1.isSelected())
                {
                    room1 = 600;
                }
                if (b.getSource() == b3)
                {
                    if (b3.isSelected())
                    {
                        boat = 60;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (b.getSource() == b2)
            {
                if (b2.isSelected())
                {
                    room2 = 850;
                }
                if (b.getSource() == b3)
                {
                    if (b3.isSelected())
                    {
                        boat = 60;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hotel a1 = new Hotel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The two easiest solutions are...

`JFormattedTextField`

[image]

and

`JSpinner`

[image]

See...

- [How to use formatted text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
- [How to use spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

For more details (for my money, `JSpinner` would be my choice)